# Route SSH and sftp using oppenvpn

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn, openvpn

I am using windows 10, [openvpn connect](https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/), the official Windows client, I could use another if needed.

Every time I need to work remotely, I need to connect to our office IP using openvpn, let's suppose that the IP I'm trying to connect to using vpn is `55.555.55.555`. I need to connect to that IP if I need to work using SSH or SFTP.

How to restrict the VPN to those connections? I don't want my browsing nor my other activities to be done using this vpn, for privacy but also for bandwidth, I have unlimited bandwidth at home, the office doesn't. I don't want to make them pay for bandwidth, and I don't want to slow the internet for whoever is using it in the office.

My open vpn file look like this

```
setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1
client
server-poll-timeout 4
nobind
remote 55.555.55.555 1194 udp
remote55.555.55.555 1194 udp
remote 55.555.55.555 1194 tcp
remote 55.555.55.555 1194 udp
remote 55.555.55.555 1194 udp
remote 55.555.55.555 1194 udp
remote 55.555.55.555 1194 udp
remote 55.555.55.555 1194 udp


# I added those 3 lines below
pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway"
route-nopull
route 55.555.55.555

dev tun
dev-type tun
ns-cert-type server
setenv opt tls-version-min 1.0 or-highest
reneg-sec 604800
sndbuf 100000
rcvbuf 100000
auth-user-pass
# NOTE: LZO commands are pushed by the Access Server at connect time.
# NOTE: The below line doesn't disable LZO.
comp-lzo no
verb 3
setenv PUSH_PEER_INFO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the client conf (ovpn) has no `redirect-gateway` option (or any `route` you don't desire). Add:

```
pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway"
```

in case the server pushes the option. You might also want:

```
route-nopull
```

if you really want to avoid any route that are pushed to you behind the scene by the server.

Then you can add the `route` you need to the conf:

```
route ip_of_ssh_server
route ip_of_sftp_server
```

Comment: I don't see `redirect-gateway` nor `route`, I added the 3 lines, didn't work. Please see my question, I edited it to include the openvpn file. The IP of the ssh server is the same as the IP of the sftp server.  The vpn is working but I'm still using the vpn IP to browse the internet, it did not restrict the vpn connection to ssh/stp only

Comment: No idea. Maybe it's because the client is openvpn3-based and therefore doesn't work with every option in 2.x clients.

Comment: i could use another VPN client if you have a recommendation

Comment: Try https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/ instead perhaps.

Comment: Do you know any client for mac that can do that? because my co-workers use mac and they want to do the same when they learned that I did it :) And what about Android. By the way, isn't there similar option for openvpn client version 3 or did they drop the feature completely? because that version is cross platform

Comment: For Android you can use https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn (without enabling the openvpn3 core). I am not sure if there are / were any openvpn 2.x based client available for Apple OSes/devices. If the VPN server belongs to your company, you may want to ask whoever manages it to stop pushing `redirect-gateway` and etc. (inappropriate/unnecessary `route`(s), DNS server)

Comment: @Lynob Maybe https://tunnelblick.net/ (for mac)